# SSIS Execute SQL Task throwing ORA-01008: not all variables bound error

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have an Execute SQL task (SQL 2008) where I'm using two SSIS variables to interact with an Oracle database:

```
DECLARE ParamTest number; TempOutputRun varchar(255);
ParamTest := ?;
TempOutputRun := ?;

BEGIN
IF ParamTest = 0 THEN

   SELECT CAST(OUTPUT_RUN_ID AS VARCHAR(15)) AS OUTPUT_RUN_ID FROM GL_EXTRACT_STATUS WHERE STATUS='NEW' ORDER BY OUTPUT_RUN_ID ASC;

ELSE

   SELECT TempOutputRun AS OUTPUT_RUN_ID FROM DUAL; 

END IF
;
END;
```

I'm getting the error ORA-01008 on execution and I'm not sure why. Both variables have values, and are set to the correct datatypes with Parameter Names in mapping of 0 and 1 respectively.  The ELSE part of this statement should be the one tripped by the current conditions I'm testing under.

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm stumped (and quite frustrated, to be perfectly honest).

Thanks!

Valkyrie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about SSIS, it seems to me you need to select...into in your code:

```
SELECT CAST(OUTPUT_RUN_ID AS VARCHAR(15)) AS OUTPUT_RUN_ID
  INTO some_var
  FROM ...
 WHERE ...
```

and

```
SELECT TempOutputRun AS output_run_id
  INTO another_var
  FROM dual;
```

I don't quite get why the ora-01008. Running the select from dual in a PL/SQL block as written gives me an ora-06550.

Comment: Sho nuff that did it! Thanks, DCookie!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following syntax

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
.....
BEGIN

.....

END;
END;
```